# Como resolver el error Un certificado https valido se encontro pero no es accesible al ejecutar una app web en Visual Studio Mac?

Tags: visual-studio, macos, certificado-ssl

Buen Dia. Como resolver el error Un certificado https valido se encontro pero no es accesible a traves de las particiones seguras al ejecutar una aplicacion web en Visual Studio Mac?
Ejecuto el comando: dotnet dev-certs https pero no resuelve el problema.
Trato de evitar de resetear la cadena de llaves. Hay que copiar un certificado? Cual?.
Gracias.

Comment: Tienes el certificado instalado en el KeyChain?

Comment: Gracias. Si tengo el certificado en el login keychain. Ya lo resolvi haciendo una copia del keychain, reinstalando el monoframework para hacer nuevo certificado, ponerle confiar, copiandolo al system chain y ejecutar dotnet dev-certs https.